# Trying to extract unique strings from a text file in Perl

Tags: regex, perl

I am 5 days in learning perl and have this problem.
Trying to extract a certain string from a file using regular expression and put these strings in a harsh and print OUT only the unique values e.g the text file contains strings like:

```
             "placement Z  F97342" 
             "placement Z  F97342"
             "placement d  F97342"
             "placement g  F97342" 
             "placement Z  F97342"
```

Expected output :

```
            "placement Z  F97342"
            "placement d  F97342"
            "placement g  F97342"
```

Below is my code but it gives me duplicate lines with "placement Z"

```
             open(FHR, "<test.txt") or die "Cannot open file $!";

            while (<FHR>){

            chomp($_);
            $_ =~/placement/g;

            print "$_\n";

            }
```

Any help?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow and the Perl tag. Please take a moment to read [ask] and take the [tour]. When asking a question about programming (not only here, but really in general), it's important to be as precise as possible. Your question contains a lot of whitespace that looks odd. I've fixed some of the layout issues, but I don't know if your input file really has all this blank space in it, or if you just didn't know how markdown works. Please [edit] your question and make the input and expected output look _exactly_ like your real data. Please also include your **full, real code**. Thanks

Comment: Can you please explain why those two lines are considered the same: ` "placement Z  F97342" / placement Z  F97342"` ? One has two double quote signs, the other only has one double quote sign.

Comment: You say you are trying to extract a string and put it into a hash. But your code attempts neither of these things. So far all it does is print all the lines that contain the word _placement_. You need to be more specific with what you want help with. For example, you haven't told us about that hash. Is the match the key or the value? Do you want to count something? Why a hash? Again, you need to be as precise as possible. There are no half-truths in programming.

Comment: Also, if you just want to remove duplicates, see the Perl FAQ on "How can I remove duplicate elements from a list or array": http://perldoc.perl.org/perlfaq4.html#How-can-I-remove-duplicate-elements-from-a-list-or-array%3f

Comment: Okay, maybe my expression was wrong. I just want to get unique values of the strings.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You've misunderstood a bunch of things I think. You're doing a regular expression match, but then not really doing anything with the result.

What do you think:

```
        $_ =~/placement/g;
```

is doing? (Because the answer is 'nothing' right now).

And likewise - you're "just" printing `$_` as you go, so you're literally just printing every line in the file.

At what level do you need to test duplicate? Is it 'full line' or is it just the 'placement' ID, or the 'number' following it?

But if you need to test for duplicates, what you need is a hash.

Something like this will do the trick:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl

use strict;
use warnings;

open( my $input, '<', "test.txt" ) or die "Cannot open file $!";

my %seen; 

while (my $line = <$input>) {
   print $line unless $seen{$line}++;
}
```

Also:

- It's good style to use lexical file handles with 3 argument open. My example reflects this.
- get `perltidy` and use it. `perltidy -pbp` will indent and format your code to a commonly accepted standard. (You can customize this how you like - the formatting/indentation can be anything you like as long as it's *consistent*).
- You don't need to `chomp` if all you do is re-insert the linefeed by hand.
- You should ALWAYS `use strict;` and `use warnings;`.

If you were wanting to be more selective as to which bit of the line to test for duplicates, you can capture sub elements using regular expressions. Say for example - only the 'placement letter' mattered:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl

use strict;
use warnings;

open( my $input, '<', "test.txt" ) or die "Cannot open file $!";

my %seen; 

while ( <$input>) {
   my ( $placement_id ) = m/placement (\d+)/;
   print unless $seen{$placement_id}++;
}
```

Note here - I don't assign the content of `<$input>` - it's set to `$_`, but I feel as a style point you should avoid using `$_` in your code - name it if you're going to use it.

This works because both `m//` regular expression matching, and `print` both default to operating on `$_` which is "the current line". The capture brackets in the regex on the right hand side are used to populate `$placement_id` - but note you *need* the brackets on the left hand side, because otherwise `$placement_id_` will only be a 'true/false' result on whether the pattern matched.

Comment: Where is $placement_id initialized here?

Comment: It's not initialized at all - that's a meaningless action in `perl`. It's declared with `my` within the loop lexical scope. So a new 'version' of it is created for each line.

Answer (score 2):

In cases like this, there's really no need to explicitly open filehandles. Perl will automatically open any files whose names are given on the command line and you can read their data using an empty file input operator (`<>`).

So your code can be a simple as this:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;

my %seen;

while (<>) {
  print unless $seen{$_}++;
}
```

And if this code is in a file called `filter`, you can call it like this:

```
$ filter test.txt
```

Answer (score 1):

using Perl one-liner

```
> cat file.txt
             "placement Z  F97342"
             "placement Z  F97342"
             "placement d  F97342"
             "placement g  F97342"
             "placement Z  F97342"
> perl -ne  '{ print "$_" unless $data{$_}++; } ' file.txt
             "placement Z  F97342"
             "placement d  F97342"
             "placement g  F97342"
>
```